# add elixir to travis but disable default commands

Tags: elixir, travis-ci

I have the following in my travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 6.10

language: elixir
elixir:
- 1.2.2
otp_release:
- 18.2.1
```

But when running on travis I get

> ** (Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure a mix.exs file is available
>   The command "mix deps.get" failed and exited with 1 during .

I don't have the files for an elixir project, I just want elixir (iex) to be installed when running on travis. how can I disable travis from checking for Mix.project ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of suppressing running `mix`, which would be a hack, do exactly what you want to do: *just install additional packages*. `TravisCI` has [hooks for almost any lifecycle step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle):

```
install:
  - wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
  - sudo apt-get install elixir
```

Or you might put the required [installation command chunk](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like) into some shell script in your repository and use it.

*NB:* I personally do this step in `after_script` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Travis run a default command based on the project language. You can override this using the `script` parameter. See Travis docs here for more info  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Customizing-the-Build-Step